# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter when i call the constructor the activity crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use FirestoreRecyclerAdapter in my code with a query but the constructor failed.
With the log i put i see that the query function.

I will use it in a recycler view.

here the code of the adapter :
ublic class MentorChatAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter {

```
public interface Listener {
    void onDataChanged();
}

//FOR DATA
private final RequestManager glide;
private final String idCurrentUser;

//FOR COMMUNICATION
private Listener callback;

public MentorChatAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Message> options, RequestManager glide, Listener callback, String idCurrentUser) {
    super(options);
    Log.e("TAG","adapter try to create");
    this.glide = glide;
    Log.e("TAG","adapter glide");
    this.callback = callback;
    Log.e("TAG","adapter callback");
    this.idCurrentUser = idCurrentUser;
    Log.e("TAG","adapter id");
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Message model) {
    holder.updateWithMessage(model, this.idCurrentUser, this.glide);
}

@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MessageViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_forum_chat_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged() {
    super.onDataChanged();
    this.callback.onDataChanged();
}
```

}

here the code where I call the adapter and i call this in the OnCreate of my activity :

```
private void configureRecyclerView(String chatName){
    Log.e("TAG","recycler call");
    //Track current chat name
    this.currentChatName = chatName;
    Log.e("TAG","step1 ok");
    //Configure Adapter & RecyclerView
    this.mentorChatAdapter = new MentorChatAdapter(generateOptionsForAdapter(MessageHelper.getAllMessageForChat(this.currentChatName)), Glide.with(this), this, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    mentorChatAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mentorChatAdapter.getItemCount()); // Scroll to bottom on new messages
        }
    });
    Log.e("TAG","step2");
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    Log.e("TAG","Step3");
    recyclerView.setAdapter(this.mentorChatAdapter);
    Log.e("TAG","Step4");
}
// 6 - Create options for RecyclerView from a Query
private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Message> generateOptionsForAdapter(Query query){
    return new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Message>()
            .setQuery(query, Message.class)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .build();
}
```

here the code of the Query where i think there is no mistake :

```
public static Query getAllMessageForChat(String chat){
    Query q = ChatHelper.getChatCollection()
            .document(chat)
            .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
            .orderBy("dateCreated")
            .limit(50);
    Log.e("TAG","getAllMessageForChat : "+q);
    return q;
}
```

here th logcat (i only can put a png because the logcat refresh automatically) : [logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebbRT.png)

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: @MikeM. i put my logcat at the end of the question

Comment: @AlexMamo I put my logcat at the end of my question

Comment: @Arno At which particular line of code does that error occur?

Comment: @AlexMamo the error occur when i try to create a MentorChatAdapter in configurerecyclerView().